# problem with javascript array assignment, how can " == true : false" working in this code?

Tags: javascript

I am studying javascript and here is my problem.

They gave me the variable named "couldBeAnything" which can be any data type. And another variable which named result, too. I must check if the given variable is array then assign true to result. Other cases then false to result. Here is the code.

```
function checkIsArray(couldBeAnything) {
var result = true ? Array.isArray(couldBeAnything) == true : false
return result;
}
```

Sorry for my wonder, because this code is from my senior, so I can not understand it clearly, I just only understand if else, so could you please explain this code for me ? How dose it work ? Thank you very much.

Comment: It’s “_⟨condition⟩_ `?` _⟨result if true⟩_ `:` _⟨result if false⟩_”, not “_⟨result if true⟩_ `?` _⟨condition⟩_ `:` _⟨result if false⟩_”. Whoever wrote this probably confused this with Python syntax. Why not simply `return Array.isArray(couldBeAnything);`?

Comment: That _senior_ title is overrated. You should simply use `Array.isArray()`

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you for your comment, so could you please write all the code how can I use Array.isArray() in this case ?

Comment: @nguyencuc2486 Sure. I would not even use a custom function for this (Because that function already exists) - What I would do is to delete this function from the code and instead of using it like this `if( checkIsArray(arr) ) { ... }` I would check it like this: `if( Array.isArray(arr) ) { ... }` (Because that's exactly what `checkIsArray()` does, but in a confusing way)

Answer (score 0):

This is working because it's doing several pointless operations that complicate reading it, but it's really just using `Array.isArray`.

```
Array.isArray(couldBeAnything) == true
```

If an array is passed in, Array.isArray is true, true == true is true.

So what you get is, if an array is passed in:

```
var result = true ? true : false;
```

Which is true.

And for a non-array:

```
var result = true ? false : false;
```

Which is false.

This is hopefully the result of several refactorings or lazy merges, because writing this on purpose is pretty silly as others have stated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are have not been exposed to ternary operators.

```
let x=true
let result
if(x){
  result="Thats true"
}
else{
  result="No thats false"
}
console.log(result)
```

The above can be written as

```
let x=true
let result=x?"That's true":"No that's false"
console.log(result)
```

The logic is that if the expression before `?` is true then the code after the `?` will be executed and if it's false then the code after `:` will be executed.

That's simple, right?

In your case the code is wrong. It should be like this:

```
function checkIsArray(couldBeAnything) {
 var result = Array.isArray(couldBeAnything) ? true : false
 return result;
}
```

But there is no need for ternary conditions here.
You can directly use this

```
function checkIsArray(couldBeAnything) {
   return Array.isArray(couldBeAnything)
}
```